# [T1]{fontenc} package makes text unselectable for Android Adobe Reader application?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, viewers, font-encodings

Alright, here's a weird one. I'm writing a paper for my English class and am encountering some problems.** So, I put `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in my preamble and compile it.** It works!

Not so fast. I need to proofread my draft. Although I could use Foxit on my PC, I want to edit on the go, so I grab my Android tablet. I've used the annotations and highlighting on it before with other papers and it works well. So I get the file on my tablet, open it, and... **I can't do anything with text. I can add comments and drawings, but anything that selects text does not work.**

I compare my paper's `.tex` source to the template I usually use and the only thing that's different about the preamble is the use of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc]`. **I remove the package, recompile, and lo and behold I can now select, highlight, underline, and strikethrough text on my Android using Adobe Reader, the same application as before.**

**What happened?** And what is making Adobe Reader get confused over `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Here is some text. Can you highlight it? My post says you can't. Do {\it you} have
what it takes to figure out what's going wrong!?
\end{document}
```

Here's a link to the PDF compiled from the above example [(click here)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0rjsEP9jRkGRC1Ca0JYenVaYVk/edit?usp=docslist_api)

And here is a PDF compiled without the line in question [(click here)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0rjsEP9jRkGdzhZRjhvbGZPYTA/edit?usp=docslist_api)

The first PDF is unselectable, and the second is.

**Edit 1:** I realized I messed up and it wasn't `textcomp` causing the problem but `[T1]{fontenc}`. I reworded the title and question to reflect this. I'd still like to know what's up, but I can simply remove that and my paper works. It was in there because I wanted better language support, but I didn't end up using it.

**Edit 2:** Added links to PDFs.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example for others to test?

Comment: Fixed, see post. As you can see, the question's changed a little.

Comment: your mwe works fine here, I can select, highlight, etc. any word. Tested on Android 4.1.something and 4.2.2, Acrobat reader 10.5.2

Comment: You are probably using bitmap fonts. Install the cm-super fonts (large package!) or use `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: @dcmst I posted compiled PDFs to show you what is happening. I'll post android version and reader version when I get back to my tablet.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a google account so I can't download from your google drive folder.

Comment: Oh no... I'm sorry. Forgot to change the file permissions. The links should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using bitmap fonts. Install the cm-super fonts (large package!) or use `\usepackage{lmodern}`.